# Does connected set always have positive lebesgue measure? except singletone and empty set.

Tags: general-topology

I have come across a statement that connected space cannot have measure zero? but then finite set having exactly one element is connected...

Comment: Are you talking about subsets of $\Bbb R$ only? If so, you should use the fact that the connected subsets are the intervals, whether open, closed, or half-open. This includes the intervals of form $[a,a]$.

Comment: No I am talking about any metric space...

Comment: Any metric space with what measure? There are metric spaces with measures that give zero measure to open sets, even.

Comment: Lebesgue measure...

Answer (score -1):

GOT answer... Singleton is just trivial case...except for that there does not exist any connected set having **Lebesgue measure zero.**
 If the set have a  measure zero then it must have gaps in it.. implies disconnectedness.

Comment: No: take the circle (just the circumference, mind you) or even any line, in the Euclidean plane.

Comment: circle do not have lebesgue measure zero...

Comment: Sorry, but any one-dimensional subset of the plane has measure zero.

Comment: if you lower the dimension what else you will get then.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$ that I know has the property that the measure of an $n$-cube of side $r$ is $r^n$. You can easily show that anything of smaller dimension has measure zero. So it seems to me that the connection between connectedness and positive measure exists only in dimension $1$.